# Error thrown when converting date to milliseconds

Tags: javascript, angularjs

According to the docs

"The model must always be a Date object, otherwise Angular will throw an error"

However, I need to convert my date object into milliseconds for an API post, and in doing so this causes the error to be thrown.

Is it possible to resolve this without changing the input model?

For instance

```
<input type='date' ng-model='user.dateOfBirth'>
```

I would like it to remain as it is so when a user is logged in, the input data can be autofilled.

So in my controller i'm trying to do something like

```
user.dateOfBirth = $scope.user.dateOfBirth.getTime()
```

Which works, but I get the date format error.

How can I reslove this?

Comment: Try to write new directive with parsers and formatters.

Comment: How are you posting the form? Using the $http or plain HTML form POST method? It would be nice of rest of the controller code was available. And rest of the HTML code.

Comment: $http. It's a form with several views, which all have access to the same user object from a service. Once they reach the final form, this object is sent as the data for the $http request.

Comment: Please show the rest of the code - controller, html  and specifically the $http request which is performed on form submit.

Comment: Not sure it's the best solution, but will work - ``var userCopy = angular.copy(user); userCopy.dateOfBirth = userCopy.dateOfBirth.getTime(); $http({...., data: userCopy})``. That is - create a copy of the user object, modify the ``dateOfBirth`` and POST the copy. User is cloned as it's an object and two-way binding would cause an error if you change ``dateOfBirth`` on the original object to number. Using this solution assumes ``user`` object is not too complex. Otherwise the copy will be expensive.

Comment: Cool, might give that a try although the user object will be large enough JSON object. Not particularly complex, but a lot of fields. Sorry didnt post my html etc.. its just a little too large!